# How to write an html page with scripts to response in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to node.js. I am trying to write to the response an html file named `index.html` which has a reference to a javascript file `test.js`:

```
<!-- Content of index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is only one line in my `test.js`

```
console.log("asdf")
```

Now, to use node.js to display `index.html`, I wrote the following `main.js`

```
let http = require("http")
let fs = require("fs")
let hostname = "127.0.0.1"
let port = 3000

let server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  fs.readFile("./index.html", (error, html) => {
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
    response.write(html)
    response.end()
  })
})
```

I entered `node main.js` in the terminal, and typed `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` in the browser. The console shows an exception saying

> **Uncaught SyntaxError**: Unexpected token `<`

It turns out that the browser got `test.js` wrong. As shown in the image below, it seems that the browser thinks `text.js` contains the content of `index.html`.

[image]

What went wrong?

All files mentioned are organized in the following manner:

```
.
├── index.html
├── main.js
└── test.js
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `test.js`? You cannot have plain `HTML` tags in there.

Comment: As I said, there is only one line in `test.js`, `console.log("asdf")`, @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: Have you tried including `DOCTYPE` declaration, and escaping `/` at closing `</script>` when returning response text?

Comment: try adding a doctype declaration and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your server is sending the contents of `index.html` no matter what the browser is asking for. Below is a verbose example of how you may want to handle requests for `index.html` vs `test.js`.

```
let server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  if(request.url === '/' || request.url === '/index.html') {
    fs.readFile("./index.html", (error, html) => {
      response.end(html);
    });
  } else if(request.url === '/test.js') {
    fs.readFile("./test.js", (error, js) => {
      response.end(js);
    });
  } else {
    response.end('idk what to send u, sowie');
  }
});
```

As you can see, some of the code repeats! You can refactor the code to say "please try to give them the exact file they're asking for; if I hit an error when reading the file, it must not exist, therefore I will send them a 404 response."